# How can I get a list of fields that I added to one form in Salesforce?

Tags: test-setup, test-automation, selenium

I'm pretty new to Salesforce and I'm wondering if there is a way to get all the fields and HTML elements that I'm using with those forms to do some future testing with cypress and selenium. Does anyone know how we can get a list of fields and elements from any dashboard, and any form from Salesforce?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please use relevant tags on your questions; none of these tags are related to the topic.

Comment: Specifics will help produce a good answer to your question (see [ask] and [help/on-topic]). What have you tried, and where are you stuck? Forms aren't really a basic component of Salesforce, so we need to know more about what you're doing and where you are working.